# CXF Keystore security - org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Empty username for specified action

Tags: web-services, cxf, keystore

I'm trying to use keystore security but I'm, hitting the following problem and not sure how to proceed further. ***org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Empty username for specified action***.
 Here is my setup.

**My Certificates are generated by the following commands**

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias aka -keypass myAliasPassword -keystore privatestore.jks -storepass keyStorePassword -dname "CN=aka" -keyalg RSA

keytool -selfcert -alias aka -keystore privatestore.jks -storepass keyStorePassword -keypass myAliasPassword

keytool -export -alias aka -file key.rsa -keystore privatestore.jks -storepass keyStorePassword

keytool -import -alias aka  -file key.rsa -keystore publicstore.jks -storepass keyStorePassword
```

**and they look like this**

```
C:\test\employee-usertoken>keytool -list -v -keystore privatestore.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: myalias
Creation date: Apr 29, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=myCN
Issuer: CN=myCN
Serial number: 517e8a5e
Valid from: Mon Apr 29 10:57:34 EDT 2013 until: Sun Jul 28 10:57:34 EDT 2013
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  AE:D8:7E:89:33:55:82:41:30:88:6D:D3:F7:7E:CA:AD
         SHA1: 02:A5:11:E7:D1:EB:61:0E:39:2C:8D:50:EF:EB:46:88:DF:86:34:94
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3


*******************************************
*******************************************

C:\test\employee-usertoken>keytool -list -v -keystore publicstore.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: myalias
Creation date: Apr 29, 2013
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=myCN
Issuer: CN=myCN
Serial number: 517e8a5e
Valid from: Mon Apr 29 10:57:34 EDT 2013 until: Sun Jul 28 10:57:34 EDT 2013
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  AE:D8:7E:89:33:55:82:41:30:88:6D:D3:F7:7E:CA:AD
         SHA1: 02:A5:11:E7:D1:EB:61:0E:39:2C:8D:50:EF:EB:46:88:DF:86:34:94
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3


*******************************************
*******************************************



C:\test\employee-usertoken>
```

**My Client Spring config is as follows**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

      <bean id="clientKeystoreTokenCallback" class="com.jpmorgan.ibanker.client.ClientKeyStoreTokenCallback" />

       <jaxws:client id="empGreetClient"
                  serviceClass="com.jpmorgan.ibanker.EmployeeGreet"
                  address="http://localhost:100/employee-usertoken/webservices/EmpGreet" >        
                <jaxws:outInterceptors> 
                    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor"> 
                        <constructor-arg> 
                            <map>
                               <entry key="action" value="Signature"/>                     
                               <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="client_sign.properties"/>
                               <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                                  <ref bean="clientKeystoreTokenCallback"/>
                               </entry>
                            </map>
                        </constructor-arg> 
                    </bean> 
                </jaxws:outInterceptors> 
        </jaxws:client>

</beans>
```

**My server side spring config is as follows**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<bean id="keyStoreTokenCallback" class="com.jpmorgan.ibanker.ServerKeyStoreTokenCallback" />
      <jaxws:endpoint 
      id="empGreetSecure" 
      implementor="com.jpmorgan.ibanker.EmployeeGreetImpl" 
      address="/EmpGreet" >   
             <jaxws:inInterceptors>
              <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
                 <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="action" value="Signature"/>                     
                       <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="server_sign.properties"/>
                       <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                          <ref bean="keyStoreTokenCallback"/>
                       </entry>
                    </map>
                 </constructor-arg>
              </bean>
           </jaxws:inInterceptors>

     </jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

**The client_sign properties file is as follows**

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=JKS
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=keyStorePassword
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=aka
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=publicstore.jks
```

**The server_sign properties is as follows**

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=JKS
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=keyStorePassword
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=aka
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=privatestore.jks
```

**The stack trace is as follows**

```
2013-04-29 15:04:06,827 [Main Thread] INFO  org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean - Creating Service {http://ibanker.jpmorgan.com/}EmployeeGreetService from class com.jpmorgan.ibanker.EmployeeGreet
2013-04-29 15:04:07,748 [Main Thread] WARN  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://ibanker.jpmorgan.com/}EmployeeGreetService#{http://ibanker.jpmorgan.com/}getEmployee has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Empty username for specified action.
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:226)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    at $Proxy36.getEmployee(Unknown Source)
    at com.jpmorgan.ibanker.client.EmpGreetClient.main(EmpGreetClient.java:20)
Exception in thread "Main Thread" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Empty username for specified action.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)
    at $Proxy36.getEmployee(Unknown Source)
    at com.jpmorgan.ibanker.client.EmpGreetClient.main(EmpGreetClient.java:20)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Empty username for specified action.
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:226)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    ... 2 more
```

I have googled around etc but with no luck.Couple of similar questions on mailing lists have been unanswered.I would appreciate if someone here can help me with this.

**I'm using java 1.6 and cxf 2.7.x**

Answer (score 0):

Because a given Keystore may contain more than one key you need to specify the name of the one you want to use. This is done by setting the user property, just add the following to your client spring:

```
<entry key="user" value="aliasOfKeytoUse"/>
```